# Why does my monitor have a black screen but the power light is blinking green?

Tags: display, troubleshooting, hardware-failure

I have a ViewSonic VA912b 19" display I use as a secondary monitor.  When I turn it on, the power light is green for a few seconds, and then switches to blinking green.  The display stays black.

Windows thinks the monitor is on, as it shows up in the control panel as a second monitor.

If I unplug the DVI cable, it displays a "No Signal" message and the power light goes to amber, which means it went to sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Make sure the DVI connector is securely connected.
2. Unplug the power cable from the monitor.
3. Press and hold the power button on the monitor for 30 seconds.
4. Re-connect the power cable.

The monitor came back on at that point.

Comment: From anonymous user: "When I tried this, it took about ten minutes for it to turn automatically on."

Answer (score 0):

If it is showing an orange screen:

Just go to All settings, and make it a Duplicate Screen. It will come up, no need to unplug the wire or something.